# How to use nested execute for a procedure

Tags: plsql

I am new to oracle. I am using oracle 19c database. I am trying to create a nested execution inside 'execute immediate' clause using PL/SQL but getting error due to invalid syntax or missing characters. What am i missing in the procedure? Thanks in advance!

Note: **exec dbms_pdb.exec_as_oracle_script** is a procedure which can be executed in PDB container.

**PL/SQL:**

```
DECLARE
 err_code EXCEPTION;
 PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(err_code, -4043);
BEGIN
 execute immediate ''exec dbms_pdb.exec_as_oracle_script(''''alter type WRI$_REPT_ASH_OMX compile'''')'';
 execute immediate ''exec dbms_pdb.exec_as_oracle_script(''''alter type WRI$_REPT_AUTO_INDEX compile'''')'';
 execute immediate ''exec dbms_pdb.exec_as_oracle_script(''''alter type WRI$_REPT_ASH_OMX compile'''')'';
 execute immediate ''exec dbms_pdb.exec_as_oracle_script(''''alter type WRI$_REPT_AUTO_INDEX compile'''')'';
 execute immediate ''exec dbms_pdb.exec_as_oracle_script(''''alter package PRVT_EMX compile body'''')'';
 EXCEPTION
   WHEN err_code THEN NULL;
END;
/
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 22:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXEC" when expecting one of the following:
* & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk
member submultiset
ORA-06550: line 5, column 62:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:
) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec between || multiset char member byte submultiset
```

Comment: You can retry like this : `execute immediate 'exec dbms_pdb.exec_as_oracle_script(''alter type WRI$_REPT_ASH_OMX compile'')';`

Comment: Its gives me another error:                                                                                  DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedures can be called in anonymous blocks (or other procedures) without any extra syntax:

You've got three different ways of executing something in a single line, you only need one. I assume `dbms_pdb` is used because you've got a pluggable database, meaning that you need to use this specific package.

```sql
begin
 dbms_pdb.exec_as_oracle_script('alter type WRI$_REPT_ASH_OMX compile');
end;
```

---

The syntax highlighting is telling you something, your `exec` looks like it's normal code not a string, which it should be. Removing a few quotes you can see what it should look like:

```sql
BEGIN
 execute immediate 'dbms_pdb.exec_as_oracle_script(''alter type WRI$_REPT_ASH_OMX compile'')';
END;
```

`exec` is not used in PL/SQL, it's for executing procedures without an anonymous block in SQL*Plus.

Comment: First code works